# Testing websites for Firefox

Tags: firefox, compatibility

What versions do you test with when testing for Firefox compatibility? Firefox 3 is a no-brainer, but do you then test for 4, 5, 6, 7, *and* 8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do the latest version, and a quick check with the previous if you really want. There's a [post someone did a few months](http://blog.gesteves.com/2011/09/25/i-love-chromes-automatic-updates/) back with graphs showing what happens to various browsers' versions once a new one comes out. It was primarily about Chrome, because of its automatic updating, but he also saw that since 4 Firefox has been doing basically the same thing: as soon as a new version is released, the previous one basically disappears and is no longer a consideration. (Once you factor in the people that are stuck on 3.6, which you're already aware of.)

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was wondering. Since Firefox is on a Chrome-like update schedule, if everyone upgrades more quickly now.

Answer (score 4):

I just go with 3.6 and the newest there is as there are not that many differences between them. Unless you use some really bleeding edge stuff, you should be OK with similar approach.

Answer (score 3):

I test with 3.6 and the latest version. I'm adding in the Android version soon although I don't anticipate there being any big differences there. Unless you're doing HTML5 stuff or something else along those lines you probably won't need to test every version.